# Sirikit integration with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, sirikit

I need to provide SiriKit feature to my Flutter application.
It is not very clear for me if it is possible or not.

For my point of view, it is not possible because Flutter does not support Bitcode generation.

In parallele I can see that bit code support is planned or some people have done some tests regarding this.

Can someone clarify the status ?

Comment: Siri is free, so I prefer that.  However, there's other voice assistants out there ... I haven't used this yet, but it seems easy to integrate into flutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXp1yGZURUM&ab_channel=AlanAI

Answer (score 3):

1. For SiriKit APIs

   - [Flutter Platform Chanel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

     > Flutter uses a flexible system that allows you to call platform-specific APIs whether available in Java or Kotlin code on Android, or in Objective-C or Swift code on iOS.

---

2. for bit code support  see :

   - [Creating an iOS Bitcode enabled app (experimental) · flutter/flutter Wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-an-iOS-Bitcode-enabled-app-(experimental))

     - also read [Add Bitcode support for iOS · Issue #15288 · flutter/flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15288)

---

3. Note :

   - To be clear and  i didn't use sirikit even for normal development